# ListView with ArrayAdapter not showing content on Android 11

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-11

In our android app the advanced settings are shown in its own listview under the normal settings. By default the listview is only populated if a password is entered beforehand.
This worked fine until we tested the app on Android 11. Now if the password is entered the listview stays empty. Debugging showed that the ArrayAdapter connected to the listview does get populated with the correct data however. Testing on a Android 10 device or lower works perfectly fine.

Any attempts to further debug or consulting the android migration guide yielded no results. Anyone got a shot?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <View
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:background="@color/BlueDark" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/settings_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:divider="@color/Blue"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"></ListView>

    <View
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:background="@color/Blue" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/advanced_settings_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/Green"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:background="@color/BlueDark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The ArrayAdapter:

```
public class SettingsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SettingsItemDataModel> {

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtSettingLabel;
        TextView txtSetting;
    }

    Context mContext;

    public SettingsListAdapter(ArrayList<SettingsItemDataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        SettingsItemDataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtSettingLabel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.setting_list_child_label);
            viewHolder.txtSetting = convertView.findViewById(R.id.setting_list_child_setting);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.txtSettingLabel.setText(dataModel.getSettingPair()[0]);
        viewHolder.txtSetting.setText(dataModel.getSettingPair()[1]);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Activity(The relevant parts only. updateAdvancedSettings() gets called when the user entered the password correctly):

```
private ArrayList<SettingsItemDataModel> settings;
private ListView advancedSettingsListView;
private SettingsListAdapter advancedSettingsListAdapter;
private ArrayList<SettingsItemDataModel> advancedSettings = new ArrayList<>();

private void setupListViews(View tabView) {

    settings = new ArrayList<>();

    for (SettingsItemDataModel.Identifier key : SettingsService.getInstance().getSettings().keySet()) {

        SettingsItemDataModel chldData = new SettingsItemDataModel(key, SettingsService.getInstance().getSettings().get(key));

        settings.add(chldData);
    }

    ListView settingsListView = tabView.findViewById(R.id.settings_list_view);
    SettingsListAdapter settingsListAdapter = new SettingsListAdapter(settings, context);
    settingsListView.setAdapter(settingsListAdapter);
    settingsListView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        if (!isNavigationLocked()) {
            Object object = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            SettingsItemDataModel dataModel = (SettingsItemDataModel) object;
            if (SettingsItemDataModel.Identifier.ADV_SETTINGS.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showAdvancedSettingsDialog();
            } else if (SettingsItemDataModel.Identifier.LANGUAGE.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (FASTMODE.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showInputSettingsRadioDialog(dataModel);
            }
        }
    });

    advancedSettingsListView = tabView.findViewById(R.id.advanced_settings_list_view);
    advancedSettingsListAdapter = new SettingsListAdapter(advancedSettings, context);
    advancedSettingsListView.setAdapter(advancedSettingsListAdapter);
    advancedSettingsListView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        if (!isNavigationLocked()) {
            Object object = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            SettingsItemDataModel dataModel = (SettingsItemDataModel) object;

            if (DEL_ALL_MAILS.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showSimpleSettingsDialog(dataModel);
            } else if (IMG_FILE_TYPE.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showInputSettingsRadioDialog(dataModel);
            } else if (IMG_COMP_LEV.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showInputSettingsSeekBarDialog(dataModel);
            } else if (SWIPE.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showInputSettingsRadioDialog(dataModel);
            } else if (ZIP_COMP_TYPE.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showInputSettingsRadioDialog(dataModel);
            } else if (ZIP_COMP_LEV.equals(dataModel.getSettingsIdentifier())) {
                showInputSettingsSpinnerDialog(dataModel);
            } else {
                showInputSettingsDialog(dataModel);
            }
        }
    });
    settingsListView.invalidate();
    advancedSettingsListView.invalidate();
}

public void updateAdvancedSettings() {

    advancedSettings.clear();

    LinkedHashMap<SettingsItemDataModel.Identifier, String[]> advSettingData = null;
    advSettingData = SettingsService.getInstance().getAdvancedSettings();

    for (SettingsItemDataModel.Identifier key : advSettingData.keySet()) {

        SettingsItemDataModel chldData = new SettingsItemDataModel(key, advSettingData.get(key));

        advancedSettings.add(chldData);
    }
    try {
        SettingsService.getInstance().saveExtAdvancedSetting();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. I have to call

```
advancedSettingsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

manually after I populated the adapter. For whatever reason this was seemingly done automatically from the OS in previous versions.

Comment: it is not working in my case